# how to disable soft delete from a GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

as mentioned in the [GCP announcement](https://cloud.google.com/resources/storage/soft-delete-announce?hl=en) the gcs soft delete feature should have been activated by GCP. I can already see an increase on the total number of bytes present in the bucket (that match the 7 day default retention). However, I am not able to find any way to disable the feature in the UI or the [terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_bucket).

Do you know how to disable this feature for a bucket?

I tried looking into the terraform provider as well as the CLI docuementation. Googling also yielded no result.

Comment: I didn't get any additional communication about the feature. I think it's too early in March. Wait a few days/weeks and an official announcement before starting working on it.

Comment: Do you have **Soft Delete** enabled for one of your buckets? AFAIK, this feature has not been rolled out yet for all customers. As of today, there is still concern internally on how to name the feature's options (duration versus retention, etc.). Example: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/17127

Comment: AFAIK the feature is being rolled out automatically (some buckets are showing increased storage size without any other explaination).

Comment: I have updated the question to be clearer but my organisation is neither in Private preview nor a Trusted Tester, However I can definitaly see an increase in stored bytes on GCS that corresponds to the default soft-delete retention period of 7 days.

Comment: `gcloud storage buckets update --clear-soft-delete gs://<bucket_name>` looks like the solution form [this post](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Cloud-Hub/GCS-Soft-Delete-Objects-Very-Bad-Experience/m-p/720339#M6122)

Comment: Correct, I tested it and it works. looking to the http logs, the body is this one `{"name": "<bucket name>", "softDeletePolicy": null}`. You can try to do the same with terraform.

Comment: Create and delete some files in a bucket. To confirm if soft delete is enabled use this command `gcloud alpha storage ls gs://BUCKET/PATH --soft-deleted` to list soft deleted files.

Comment: Don't test with terraform. I checked the code in GitHub and the feature is not yet here.

Comment: This command will show if soft delete is enabled: `gcloud alpha storage buckets describe gs://BUCKET`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers, I'll do an answer for future people to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the soft-delete feature on a given bucket you can use the gcloud cli:

```
gcloud storage buckets update --clear-soft-delete gs://<bucket-name>
```

In order to check if the feature is activated on your bucket and what is the soft-delete retention policy, you can use the alpha gcloud command:

```
gcloud storage buckets describe gs://<bucket-name>
```

and look for the `soft_delete_policy` block.

Comment: You need the latest version of gcloud CLI to use these command. Or use Cloud Shell

Answer (score 1):

Found how to disable the feature through the UI [in this article](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/use-soft-delete).

Here's a recap:

1. In the Google Cloud console, go to the Cloud Storage Buckets page.
   Go to **Buckets** ([direct link](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser))
2. In the list of buckets, click the name of the bucket you want to
   remove the soft delete policy from.
3. Click the **Protection** tab.
4. In the **Soft delete policy** section, click **Delete**.
5. Click **Confirm**.

Comment: This was quite straight forward